# Is there a call in vb.net I can make to determine daylight savings time?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, time

Is there a way in VB.Net to determine if the timezone the current system has daylight savings time in effect?  Of course I can get the offset from GMT using the "z"/"zz" formatting option, but that doesn't tell me if DST is in effect for the current timezone or if the current timezone is in standard time...or if DST/Standard time aren't even an issue in the timezone for the system.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 6):

[TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm, I couldn't get this to work...I'm using VS 2008.  I did get the following to work though:  TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName

Answer (score 4):

Just use `Now.IsDaylightSavingTime`. It returns a boolean value.

Stephen B. Craver

Answer (score 3):

You can use for dateinstance:

```
DateTimeInstance.IsDaylightSavingTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the answers provided would work...I just couldn't figure out how to get them working however.  There is no "IsDaylightSavingTime" method available to me.  I ended up using:

```
   TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName
```